# Cómo cerrar publicidad de google con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy intentando cerrar una publicidad de google haciendo click en la x, pero trato de ubicarlo con fullxpath y no lo encuentra al momento de ejecutar el codigo. Intente de otra manera hacer click partiendo del body unos 5 pixeles a la derecha y abajo, ya que me percate que haciendo click en donde sea desaparece la publicidad, aun así no he tenido éxito. Espero que puedan ayudarme, ya que aun sigo estancado aquí.

A continuación les dejo mi código que hice con las soluciones que realicé.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div'))) \
    .click() 

# Libraries
from threading import Thread

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd


# Options of navigation
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-maximized')
options.add_argument('User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\franc\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)

# Inicializamos el navegador
driver.get('https://cursosdev.com/coupons')

# Ubicamos el boton de siguiente y le damos click
last_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[5]/div/nav/nav/div[2]/div[2]/span/a[12]')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, last_page))) \
    .click()

# Cerramos la publicidad de Google

# METODO 1 - Ubicamos la x en la publicidad para cerra
close_publicity = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div'))) \
    .click()

# METODO 2 - Desde body movemos el mouse 5 pixeles a la derecha y abajo, y damos click para que desaparesca la publicidad
el=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La publicidad de *google adsense* se carga en etiquetas `<ins class="adsbygoogle">`. Puedes seleccionar todos los elementos de la *clase* `adsbygoogle` y ocultarlos asignando el valor `'none'` a su *propiedad css* `display`:

```py
driver.execute_script("""
for (let i of document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')){
    i.style.display = 'none';
}
""")
```

Si prefieres que los elementos de la página no se muevan al ocultar la publicidad, en lugar de `i.style.display='none'` puedes utilzar `i.style.opacity=0`:

```py
driver.execute_script("""
for (let i of document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle')){
    i.style.opacity = 0;
}
""")
```

Un saludo!